# How can I do BaseLayout/BaseComponent override In Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-client-side

ToolbarLayout.cs

```
public class ToolbarLayoutBase : LayoutComponentBase
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual void NewData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Save Click " + Text);
    }
    public virtual void UpdateData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Update Click");
    }
}
```

ToolbarLayout Razor

```
@inherits ToolbarLayoutBase
BtnSave,BtnUpdate,BtnRemove HTML Button
```

EditPage.cs

```
public class EditPageBase : ToolbarLayoutBase
{

    public override void UpdateData()
    {
        base.UpdateData();
    }

}
```

EditPage Razor

```
@inherits EditPageBase
@page "/editpage"

<ToolbarLayout  />
```

I have components as shown in the pictures above.
I want to use my "ToolbarLayout" component as a base component, and I need methods, etc. I want to change.
Like the Base Form structure in WinForm.

Comment: Please, edit the question by removing those links and pasting the actual code in their place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add classes derived from [`ComponentBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-3.0) and use `@inherits`

```cs
public class MyBaseComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IService AnInjectedService { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string AParameter { get; set; }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {        
    }   
}
```

```cs
@inherits MyBaseComponent
<h3>My derived component @AParamter</h3>

@code {
    protected override void Update()
    {
        // code overidding my base update method
        base.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
I know that. what I want to do is override the base component's methods.

Example :  IndexPage :   BasePage

Comment: @Harun:  Which methods?  How? Your question needs a lot more detail.

Comment: @HenkHolterman for example: I have five pages. Toolbar Menu is available in these five pages. Toolbar Menu component has three methods. These are Save, Update, Remove. I want to crush(override) the Update Method of this toolbar menu on my second page.